# cache and compress and minify code of wordpress

Tags: .htaccess

**Do these lines work in htaccess to apply to all mime types and all files?**

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE .*/.*
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE .*

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE */*
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE *

ExpiresByType .*/.* "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType .* "access plus 1 hour"

ExpiresByType */* "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType * "access plus 1 hour"
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Apache doesn't minify anything, you'd have to do that yourself (webpack/etc), and these directives would only apply to the front end components (it's unclear what you mean by "all files").

Comment: I just want to know which lines are correct and working

Comment: What were the results of your testing?

Comment: I do not know how to experiment

Comment: I feel it has not changed

Comment: You would have to benchmark it, run before/after tests (possibly using external tools such as Google Lighthouse).  If your front end is sufficiently small/optimized you may not be able to perceive a difference anyways.

Comment: Do you actually have an issue which appears to be caused by the size of the responses your http server sends? Or are you doing this "just because"?

Comment: @arkascha I do it for better performance for client side

Comment: And why do you think that should enhance the client side performance?

Comment: @arkascha I just want to know if these lines are syntactically correct or not?

Comment: Now what, are you trying to improve performance or are you trying to get around having to read the documentation? Sorry, don't get this wrong, but you contradict yourself and you are apparently unable to reason for what you are trying to achieve. So I assume you are doing this simply because you read somewhere that it is possible. I would advise you to concentrate on other things that are more important and have much more effect.